# Making a repeating text background on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been requested to put a sequence of text repeating as the background of a website.

It will be just a slight shade lighter then the background color, similar to physical company stationary with the name, slogan, whatever repeating covering the paper.

I mocked it up simply enough by putting the following div onto the page

```
<div style="z-index: -1; position: fixed; font-size: 20pt; color: rgb(148, 148, 148); 
text-align: justify;">Repeating Text Here Repeating Text Here Repeating Text Here</div>
```

I like this solution in general terms as using a repeating image seems like a big headache (trying to get a seamless repetition) and the text based seems like better bandwidth wise.

However, to get enough text onto the page to cover browser windows maximized at a high resolution, I am manually repeating the text in the html many times over.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this, something CSS based maybe I could say to repeat X times.

I know I could repeat the text X times into html server side with PHP, ASP.Net, etc but I am looking for something where the html source output doesn't need that text repeated like that.

I could do it JavaScript based, but then users without JavaScript won't see it.  An advantage I could see with the JavaScript would be bots like Google's won't see the repeating text and think it is an attempt to boost keyword hits.

**Comment Responses:**
The text is static, essentially it is a company slogan.  Picture if instead of SO having a pure white background it was white with a soft gray "Making the Web a Better Place" over and over again.

The issues with doing this image based I see is lack of text justify and wrap for variance of browser window width.

It would sometimes need to go:

> Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web a Better Place Making the
>   Web   a Better Place Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web a
>   Better Place

Then if you reduce the browser width it'd need to be:

> Making the Web a Better Place  Making  the    Web a Better Place
>   Making the Web a Better    Place Making the Web a Better Place Making

If you are doing that with a tiled image, you'd end up with:

> Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web
>   Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web
>   Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web

Comment: There's nothing in CSS that lets you repeat a chunk of text. You'd have to generate enough text to cover worst-case 'page size' coverage, and yes, you'll probably get dinged by search engines for stuffing in "keywords"

Comment: Is the text that needs to be repeated static or it should change from time to time?

Comment: I don't think that the image repeating is a bad solution - you would only need to download a small image of the text 1 time, and then just use the css repeating background image tag to achieve the effect.   http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/background-repeat/

Comment: @Marc B, I didn't think there was a CSS property for that, just spit balling ideas basically.

Comment: @idbentley, I'm aware of background image repetition, the issue here is text is not a pattern that can be created to where the edges will seamlessly tile to create a larger image.

Comment: It's doable with some cleaver slogan inline-block width calculation and drawing it line by line with calculating offset for the first slogan in the next line based on how much was cut in the previous one + letter/word spacing for the previous line to make it fill the line fully. Though as far as concept goes if I was to implement it I'd need to get paid for that - tons of work if it was to look perfectly typography-wise.

Comment: @Tom Tu, I get what you are saying, similar to my comment on the one given answer. It does sound like an annoying pain to get just right, the text div is much simpler but Google thinking it is keyword spam concerns me.

Comment: I'd just roll with image - but with few lines offseted related to each other and I'd swallow that it doesn't line up perfectly - doing it with text would be hell - though you'd definitely get noticed if you pulled it off :)

Comment: @Tom Tu, I've already got it working text based (see the div tag in the question). The actual content in this case is a list of about 20 services they provide, pasting those inside of the div repeatedly enough times to fill the page works visually, I just don't like it as a solution. Both for dirty code and for SEO issues.

Comment: ah, /selfslap you can fill the element with javascript and check if the height of the container the text is filling is > the page height 'pseudo code mode' ;) 
`do { el.innerHTML += ' your text couple times'; } while (el.height > page.height)` - have you tried it this way? (I've assumed that the element width == page width and then you'd have to add onresize event which would check if the el height is still > page.height if not repeat with adding more text

Comment: @Tom Tu, I did that except skipped the height check, I just maxed the output on my 1920x1080 screen then doubled it.  The extra text doesn't cause any extra scrolling, I'm assuming because of the z-index: -1 or the div's block display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I've done it via JavaScript, still open to better solutions.

I made the div in the html empty

```
<div id="Slogan" style="z-index: -1; position: fixed; font-size: 20pt; color: #999999; text-align: justify; margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 6px;"></div>
```

Then created a javascript function that is called from the body's onLoad

```
function FillSlogan()
{
    var text = '';

    for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        text += 'Making the Web a Better Place ';
    }

    $('#Slogan').html(text);
}
```

The FillSlogan function is in an include file and will be denied in robots.txt for good measure.

This way it is able to use the justification and wrapping abilities, but keeps the repeated text away from the bots.

Comment: Would you share a link to the site were you've used this?

Comment: ^ website has since been updated and no longer showcases the code mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 9):

You can play with canvas+javascript. The simplest way to create canvas and use it as background:

```
    var text = 'Making the Web a Better Place Making the Web';
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var fontSize = 24;
    canvas.setAttribute('height', fontSize);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle    = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)';
    context.font         = fontSize + 'px sans-serif';
    context.fillText(text, 0, fontSize);

    $('#elementId').css({'background-image':"url(" + canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });
```

Comment: this is jquery.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a CSS-only solution, using an inline SVG.
SVG supports a <text> tag. You may need to adjust the dimensions and viewbox to make this example fit your needs.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg width='598' height='245' viewBox='0 0 598 245' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3ctext x='30' y='40' fill='red'%3eTEXT GOES HERE%3c/text%3e%3c/svg%3e ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JavaScript, you could make a dynamic image generator as a server-side component (servlets, PHP whatever) and use it as the image source with the text to be generated specified in the URL. So something like this in your CSS (which could itself be generated by a script which would allow you to specify different text strings for the image generator):

```
body{
     background-image: url('http://example.com/myimageservlet?msg=I+want+this+text+as+my+repeating+background');
     background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: As commented above, image generation isn't needed as the text is static and I'm blanking on a way to manipulate the image to give proper wrapping of the text at variable widths.  It would need to cut off the image at the right boundary and continue the image on the next line starting at the point of cut off, which I don't think is a feasible answer.